# C#: Change Retrieval DataType for Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-binding, azure-sql-database, sqldatatypes

I'm trying to convert a project that is currently using a custom DAO framework to using Entity Framework. The system is quite large so changes to the database (a SQL Azure DB if that matters) itself aren't particularly feasible and should be avoided if possible.

The problem is with the ID column. Unfortunately when the system was created, there are some tables that have a `bigint` datatype, and some that have an `int` - but the models themselves all come from a base class having a `long` for the ID. The previous framework was able to handle this situation, but I have been unable to find a way to do it with entity framework.

Below is the most trivial example I can think of:

```
public class Context : DbContext {
    public IDbSet<Foo> Foos {get;set;}
    public IDbSet<Bar> Bars {get;set;}
}
public abstract class BaseClass {
    public long ID;
}
public class Foo : BaseClass {
    ...
}
public class Bar : BaseClass {
    ...
}
SQL Table: Foo
+-------------+
| id : bigint |
| ...         |
+-------------+
SQL Table : Bar
+-------------+
| id : int    |
| ...         |
+-------------+
```

When I try to load a `Bar` model, I get this error:

```
The 'ID' property on 'BaseClass' could not be set to a 'Int32' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Int64'.
```

I'd like to find a way to tell the system that Bar has ints, while Foo has longs. I've tried overriding `OnModelCreating` in the context and defining `HasColumnType` for `Bar`. That gave me a new error:

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
    (105,12) : error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.Int64[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=]' of member 'ID' in type 'Bar' is not compatible with 'SqlServer.int[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,StoreGeneratedPattern=Identity]' of member 'ID' in type 'CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.Bar'.
```

It seems to me that if I could only change the expected data type for the `ID` of `BaseClass` to `int` before sending the request to the server, then I should be able to up-convert to a `long` after I receive the response. Ideally, I'd like to do this on a per-class basis.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you can implicitly cast a [`bigint` to an `int` in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), it appears that the Entity framework EDM types (which is really what you're dealing with) doesn't allow an implicit transformation from a 64-bit integer type to a 32-bit integer type.

This is probably for good reason, because you could easily overflow and have values that don't fit in the `int` fields.

That said, you should have two base classes, one for an `int` ID and one for a `long` ID.  It's not pretty, but it enforces logic that you definitely want; you won't be able to store values that are larger than what can fit into an `int` in the database, so why would you want to be able to do it on the code level?  The Entity framework is doing the right thing here in not letting you apply that transformation.

Comment: Yeah - that's what I was afraid of. I recognize that I'm trying to fix a wrong with another wrong. I was just hoping I'd be able to avoid major sweeping changes with a few little tricks. Everything I've tried ended up not working so I think I've resigned myself to doing exactly what you've recommended.

If no better solutions come in, I'll mark this one as correct.

Comment: @Merwer Sometimes, the truth hurts, please don't shoot the messenger =)

Comment: Hi @casperOne Sorry to barge in with my question as it is along the same topic. Is there any way of doing the opposite. I have a table with an id of type Int. It is growing dangerously large and I'm wondering if there is a way of changing it to Long? (Entity Framwork CF 6.1)

Comment: @hjavaher You should find all the foreign key references to the primary key that is an `int` and change them to a `bigint` (as well as the primary key of course).  It shouldn't be too hard to do.